# не работает проверка на ввод числа

Tags: python, рекурсия, ввод, проверка

я пытаюсь сделать проверку на ввод числа(только числа, положительного, не дробного).
Если при запуске сразу ввести символы, то программа это поймет и всё начнется по новой, но если в другой раз ввести уже число, то после строки **return ra** функция переходит обратно к вызову проверки **maincheck()** и думает, что там введены символы. То есть после **return ra** проверка по идее должна закончиться, но она не заканчивается, а возвращается к вызову проверки и значение строки почему-то изменяется на то, что я ввел первый раз(на символы). Я не понимаю, помогите пожалуйста. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def maincheck():
    str = ""
    str = input()
    if len(str) > 10 or len(str) == 0:
        print("incorrect value, please try again")
        maincheck()
    else:
        for i in range (len(str)):
            if str[i] < '0' or str[i] > '9':
                print("incorrect value, please try again")
                maincheck()
    ra = int(str)
    return ra
h = maincheck()
print(h)
```

Comment: а что за ** в коде? и h = maincheck() print(h) странно выглядят - вне кода оказались. Проверьте форматирование кода в вопросе

Comment: Да, я первый раз задаю вопрос и не разобрался до конца. ** я убрал, но h = maincheck() print(h) почему-то не хотят к коду присоединяться

Comment: потому, что вы не прочитали, как надо код размещать. Там сдвиг на 8 символов.Исправил за вас, примите правку.

Comment: и добавляйте тестовые последовательности всегда.

Comment: В общем, без последовательностей и комментариев по логике работы программы, догадываться не хочется. Что не советую, так это использовать встроенный тип str в качестве имени переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо делать рекурсивный вызов функции самой из себя, у вас в результате получается, что в цикле может вызываться функция сама из себя, а возврат будет в место вызова, т.е. опять внутрь цикла. Это явно не то, что требуется. Структура кода может быть примерно такая:

```py
def maincheck():
    while True:
        num = input()
        if <проверка, что что-то не так>:
            print(<что именно не так>)
            continue
        # тут могут быть ещё проверки
        ...
        # если все проверки успешные
        return result
```

То есть делаем бесконечный цикл ввода и делаем `continue`, чтобы перейти на следующую итерацию ввода и проверок, если ввод был неправильный.
Ну и не надо перегружать встроенный тип питона `str` своей переменной, конечно.